# Divide subcommands into groups using Clap

Tags: rust, clap

I am trying to create a CLI using Clap that contains a relatively large number of subcommands.From the documentation, I would have expected the following to work:

```
#[derive(Parser)]
pub struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    pub command: Commands,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
pub enum Commands {
    /// Determine reads mapping to sample-specific MAGs
    #[command(subcommand_help_heading = "FirstHeading")]
    Subcommand1(Subcommand1Args),

    /// Create sketches from FASTA/Q file(s)
    #[command(subcommand_help_heading = "SecondHeading")]
    Subcommand2(Subcommand2Args),
}
```

However, the `subcommand_help_heading` arguments do not change the CLI. I'm expecting the output to be similar to:

```
My command line interface.

Usage: my_program <COMMAND>

FirstHeading:
  subcommand1  ...

SecondHeading:
  subcommand2 ...

Options:
  -h, --help     Print help
  -V, --version  Print version
```

Comment: Please also include the actual output - you say what you're expecting, but not what it actually produces.

Comment: Which part of the documentation makes it look like it would work? The docs of `subcommand_help_heading` says that it sets the header for the entire subcommands section. There is only one subcommands section here, though. If you had more nested subcommands then the heading would apply there. https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Command.html#method.subcommand_help_heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage text in clap has one section for subcommands, and therefore one heading. It shows all the available subcommands. You can set that header with `subcommand_help_heading`, so if your `Commands` struct had this additional attribute:

```rust
#[derive(Subcommand)]
#[command(subcommand_help_heading = "MyAwesomeHeading")]
pub enum Commands {
  // ... snip ...
}
```

you would get, for `--help`:

```
My command line interface.

Usage: my_program <COMMAND>

MyAwesomeHeading:
  subcommand1  Determine reads mapping to sample-specific MAGs
  subcommand2  Create sketches from FASTA/Q file(s)
  help         Print this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)

Options:
  -h, --help  Print help
```

As far as I can see there's no easy way to tell `clap` to include multiple subcommand headings in the main help text. But if you have multiple *nested* subcommands inside of your commands, then you can control the help text for them. For example, say we define the `Subcommand1Args` as:

```rust
#[derive(Parser)]
pub struct Subcommand1Args {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    sub: Subcommands1,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
pub enum Subcommands1 {
    // Do A
    A,
    // Do B
    B(IntArg)
}

#[derive(Parser)]
pub struct IntArg {
    arg: u32
}
```

Then by using **`subcommand1 --help`** you get:

```
Determine reads mapping to sample-specific MAGs

Usage: playground subcommand1 <COMMAND>

FirstHeading:
  a     Do A
  b     Do B
  help  Print this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)

Options:
  -h, --help  Print help
```

You can see the `FirstHeading` value from `subcommand_help_heading` applied for `Subcommand1` being used here.

Subcommands are basically nested sub-clis, and they get their own help pages.

Full code [in play.rust-lang](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=288ea1cefa2d4c15c58a45eb7cec2285).